# How to create "ORDER BY Column = 'Value'" query with SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am new to SQLAlchemy & wanted to create an SQLAlchemy query equivalent to "order by exact match first". 
Below is the SQL:

```
select word from dictionary where word like '%Time%' order by (word = 'Time') desc;
```

This is my SQLAlchemy equivalent.

```
Dictionary.query.with_entities ( Dictionary.word )
.filter(Dictionary.word.like("%{}%".format("Time")))
.order_by(Dictionary.word == "Time")
```

But it throws an error at "order_by": SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression. How to solve it ?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have `order_by(Dictionary.word = "Time")` in your actual code?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

.order_by(Dictionary.word == q,func.length(Dictionary.word))
```